# Creating a Rails' product page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, search, hyperlink, product

I'm creating a rails ecommerce site. I'm able to search for products by title with a search form, but how can I link to a page that outputs all products with specific title or category?

This is the code in my products controllers :

```rails
def index
  @products = Product.scoped
  @products = @products.where('title like ?', "%#{params[:search]}%") if params[:search]
  @products
end
```

and my store controllers has this:

```rails
def index    
  if params[:search]    
    @products = Product.search(params[:search]).title
  else    
    @products= Product.all    
  end    
end
```

Answer (score 0):

To create a link that shows products with `some` category use in your view:

```
<%= link_to 'Some', products_path(cat: :some) %>
```

You need to change your controller to:

```
@products = @products.where('title like ?', "%#{params[:search]}%") if params[:search]
@products = @products.where('category like ?', "%#{params[:cat]}%") if params[:cat]
```

I am assuming too many things though.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to filter your products based on title or category, the way you do this largely depends on how your filtering is setup in the view. If you are using a select box with specific titles you want to filter by, it would look like this in your view (within the form tag):

```
<select name='title_filter'> 
  <option value="title_1">Title 1</option>
  <option value="title_2">Title 2</option>
</select>
```

Now, when a user submits the form having selected a title, the key "title_filter" will be added to your params hash with the value that the user selected. You can use the same controller action you specified, but just have it check for your new key:

```
if params[:title_filter]
  @products = @products.where('title= ?', params[:title_filter])
else
  # fallback if no title is selected
end
```

Alternatively, you can use a link_to if you are filtering with links:

```
<%= link_to 'My Title', products_path(title: :my_title) %>
```

Also, the way you are using your `where` clause is dangerous. See the [Active Record guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#conditions)

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using this in my view. For some reason the other answers weren't working for me: <%= link_to "Tables", products_path(search: 'dining') %>